# Trying to solve CS0246 error in mvc. The type or namespace name 'XXContext' could not be found

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have an mvc project that is on the .NET Framework 4.5.2. I faced this error CS0246 when I added the IsSelected column to the table "Department" in database. After this, whenever I call the Context class, it gives the error **'The type or namespace name 'XXContext' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)'**

```
private XXContext db = new XXContext();
```

I did try to resolve by cleaning and rebuilding solution. It didn't work. Then I tried to rename the XXContext to 'HRContext' and recreated the connection string in the web-config file. The connection string was successful. Checked the properties of the class project - under application. Output type is 'Class Library'. Still getting the **same error**.

How do I know if my target framework has to be upgraded??
How do I know if deleting the temp folder would not cause further errors of problems in VS?? (Read a solution from my research online)

Any other solution will be most appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried updating the edmx in the project and running the custom tool on the data models?

Comment: yes, I did try update and refreshing the edmx file. Also tried the running the custom tool on data models

Answer (score 0):

on XXContext word, press Alt & Enter keys, the solution find assembly and suggest you location of assembly